# How to know who modified a file?

Tags: svn, vim

What do you use to see who has modify a file?

I mean, i'm working with a group of people and with svn, so my partner can see in Netbeans who has written/modified **each line** of a file! How can i see this in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for the svn blame command?

```
svn blame <filename>
```

Answer (score 2):

Start by learning how Version Control Systems work. I don't know much about SVN since I'm a Git fan, but they have basically the same purpose: manage a team (or even a single person) source code.

When you are using a VCS, and after making a few changes, you can commit your changes and push them to the main repository. When you configure the VCS in your machine, you setup your account with your name and email. That's how your commits get recognized by the VCS.

I'm not the best person on earth to talk about this, but if you are interested, Eric Sink is offering his book -*Version Control by Example*- for free (and will ship it for you for free too). I got the book the last year, and while it was not extensive or advanced, it introduced me to a bunch of VCSs and I made the decision to stick with Git.

Finally, if you want to see the changes in VIM, you'll need a plugin for that. NetBeans has a plugin for SVN.

Answer (score 0):

I found also this to get blame inside vim:

http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2009-10/0776.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You want the *annotate* a.k.a. *blame* functionality found in Subversion as well as many other revision control systems.

With the help of the [vcscommand plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90), you can display this information in Vim, either as an augmented scratch buffer (`:VCSAnnotate`), or a window split to the left of the original buffer  (`:VCSAnnotate!`). It also offers all sort of other commands related to version control, and supports CVS/SVN/SVK/git/hg/bzr.